# Get date and time to appear from ASP.NET calender

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Hi iv got an ASP site to book flights, when i select a date from the calender and display that date in a textbox it displays the date but then only 00:00:00

here is my code for that bit:

```
protected void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dayToFly = Convert.ToString(Calendar.SelectedDate.Date);
    txtDate.Text = dayToFly;
}

protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dayToFly = Convert.ToString(Calendar.SelectedDate.Date);
    destination = dropDestinations.SelectedValue;
    amountofpeople = Convert.ToInt16(dropAmount.SelectedValue);

    lblInfo.Text = "You would like to Fly on " + dayToFly + " to " + 
        destination + " with " + amountofpeople + " people";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the standard ASP.NET Calendar control? If so it will only give you a date, with no time associated ( that's why you get '00:00:00' for the time ).

You'll probably need to use third party date/time picker control(s), that allows the user to select both date AND time. I use the Telerik one here at work, but it costs $$$.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

I'm sure there are free ones available though.